# rails database query is resulting activeRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, spree

I am using Spree Commerce for developing my E-commerce site. When I write

```
self.where("user_id = ?", user_id)**
```

for accessing database it is showing `ActiveRecord::Relation` and when I am using

```
self.where("user_id = ?", user_id).first
```

it is not returning anything. I am using

`Spree::Modelname.actionname` in the view file to access the data.

Can anyone help me in getting a data from database in rails 3.2.

Comment: Are you sure self is what you think it is when the statement is being executed?

Comment: I have tried changing the self to Spree::Wishlist also, but it is also showing the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.where(...)` called on a model class will return a relation. You call `.first` or `.last` on it, if it is a single record, or `.all`, `.to_a`, `.limit(...)` for a set of records.

If this doesn't work, ensure you are using the Spree user class:

```
Spree.user_class.where("user_id = ?", user_id).first
```

or:

```
Spree.user_class.where(:user_id => user_id).first
```

or Ruby 1.9+ hash syntax:

```
Spree.user_class.where(user_id: user_id).first
```

That assumes that Spree's user class is a model backed by a table that has a "user_id" column, and that there is a record in the database table that has a user_id equal to the user_id you pass into that.

Comment: Yea this query is working fine. But I am actually adding the spree-wishlist extensiom in my site and i want to generate a link to the wishlist in the homepage. So when i am trying the same thing with the wishlist model it is not showing anything.

Comment: For wishlist, it looks like it would be `Spree::Wishlist.where(:name => "some wishlist name")` or lookup of wishlist by user_id, `Spree::Wishlist.joins(Spree.user_class.table_name.to_sym).where(Spree.user_class.table_name.to_sym => {:user_id => user_id}).first`. Probably want to replace all of the Spree.user_class and Spree.user_class.table_name.to_sym with the values of those so as not to clutter the code unless you are writing a generic extension/gem.

Comment: Be sure to read through [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) thoroughly and prior to that get a decent understanding of SQL if you don't have one already, because you'll need it as time goes on.